# Multinomial Logistic Regression Predictors Set Up

Tags: regression, logistic-regression, multinomial

I would like to use a multinomial logistic regression to get win probabilities for each of the 5 horses that participate in any given race using each horses previous average speed.

```
RACE_ID    H1_SPEED     H2_SPEED    H3_SPEED    H4_SPEED    H5_SPEED    WINNING_HORSE
1          40.482081    44.199627   42.034929   39.004813   43.830139   5
2          39.482081    42.199627   41.034929   41.004813   40.830139   4
```

I am stuck on how to handle the independent variables for each horse given that any of the 5 horses average speed can be placed in any of `H1_SPEED` through `H5_SPEED`.

Given the fact that for each race I can put any of the 5 horses under `H1_SPEED` meaning there is no real relationship between `H1_SPEED` from `RACE_ID 1` and `H1_SPEED` from `RACE_ID 2` other than the arbitrary position I selected.

Would there be any difference if the dataset looked like this -

- For `RACE_ID 1` I swapped `H3_SPEED` and `H5_SPEED` and changed `WINNING_HORSE` from `5` to `3`
- For `RACE_ID 2` I swapped `H4_SPEED` and `H1_SPEED` and changed `WINNING_HORSE` from `4` to `1`

```
RACE_ID    H1_SPEED     H2_SPEED    H3_SPEED    H4_SPEED    H5_SPEED    WINNING_HORSE
1          40.482081    44.199627   43.830139   39.004813   42.034929   3
2          41.004813    42.199627   41.034929   39.482081   40.830139   1
```

Is this an issue, if so how should this be handled? What if I wanted to add more independent features per horse?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change in that way your dataset, because each feature (column) has a meaning and probably it depends on the values of the other features. You can imagine it as a six dimensional hyperplane, if you change the value of a feature the position of the point in the hyperplane changes, it does not remain stationary. 
If you deem that a feature is useless to solve your problem (i.e. it is independent from the target), you can drop it or avoid to use it during the training phase of your model.

**Edit**

To solve your specific problem you may add a parameter for each speed column that takes care of the specific horse which is running with that speed. It is a sort of data augmentation, in order to add more problem related features to your model.

```
RACE_ID   H1_SPEED  H1_HORSE   H2_SPEED  H2_HORSE  ... WINNING_HORSE
1         40.482081        1   44.199627        2  ...             5
2         39.482081        3   42.199627        5  ...             4
```

I've invented the number associated to each horse, but it seems that this information is present in your dataset.

Comment: The problem is that the order of the features is interchangeable per sample and each feature (column) has no relationship to that same feature (column) from a different row

Comment: There are 5 features per row and I put them each in an arbitrary column

Comment: Maybe, I'm not understanding, but it seems that you want to address the fact that the horse speed is not related to the horse. So, why not create a new feature for each speed column that identifies the horse? In that way, you take into consideration both the speed and the horse that is running with that speed.

Comment: Can you share an example of doing this or any links or terms I can search to see how to do this? @Andrea

Comment: I've just edited the previous answer, check if it convinces you.